# cli s3 syncing between buckets returns NoSuchTagSetError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

here's what I did when syncing (config for wasabi, policy action contains `s3:PutObject`, `s3:PutObjectAcl`, `s3:GetObject`, `s3:DeleteObject` and all files are public except `s3://backup-bucket/`):

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
  -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
  amazon/aws-cli s3 sync \
  s3://source-bucket/ \
  s3://backup-bucket/ \
  --profile wasabi \
  --endpoint-url=https://s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com
```

and it returned:

```
copy failed: s3://source-bucket/sample.txt to s3://backup-bucket/sample.txt
An error occurred (NoSuchTagSetError) when calling the GetObjectTagging
operation: There is no tag set associated with the bucket.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I missed this [part](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html):

> `--copy-props` (string) Determines which properties are copied from the source S3 object.

> If `--metadata-directive` is set, the `--copy-props` parameter will be disabled and will have no affect on the transfer.